# Hospital originated infections and mishaps

Tags: data-request, usa, medical

[NPR](http://www.npr.org/blogs/health/2014/10/21/357618079/hospitals-struggle-to-beat-back-serious-infections) and other news organizations are citing a dataset analyzed by Kaiser from the CDC:

```
Created with Datawrapper
Source: Kaiser Health News analysis of CDC data Get the data
```

Would anyone know where the raw data set comes from?

I am interested in more details, especially hospital names, type of incidents, and location (city, state, zip code, etc).

Answer (score 9):

The data referenced appears to be an aggregation of Hospital Acquired Infections which are part of the CMS Hospital Compare family of data sets.

The various measures included in the dataset are listed at  http://www.medicare.gov/hospitalcompare/Data/Measures-Displayed.html

There are a number of ways to access the raw data which are listed at http://www.medicare.gov/hospitalcompare/Resources/Download-Data.html including zipped archives of CSVs, APIs at data.medicare.gov, and more.

If you're going to visit one line.. go to https://data.medicare.gov/Hospital-Compare/Healthcare-Associated-Infections-Hospital/77hc-ibv8

Comment: Thanks for the last link. Seems like SCORE column is useful, along with Compared with National. How does one know what the range of SCORE is and what the values mean? Seems like the SCORE value is based on each row.

Comment: The score definitely depends o the measure/measure ID which are listed and sort of explained at http://www.medicare.gov/hospitalcompare/Data/Measures-Displayed.html. Some measures may have normal ranges and standard while others will not. Welcome to healthcare quality measures ;)